# How to play ISampleProvider

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I want to convert an `ISampleProvider` to an `WaveStream` so I can be able to play it.How do I do this?

```
ISampleProvider mySamples = new mySampleProvider();
IWavePlayer mySpeaker = new WaveOut();

//Convert ISampleProvider to WaveStream Here

mySpeaker.Init(mySamples);
mySpeaker.Play();
```

Where mySampleProvider is a class that inherits from `ISampleProvider` but does not have `WaveStream` as a base class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest NAudio has an extension method on `IWavePlayer.Init` so your code should compile. What version of NAudio are you using?

Also, you don't need to pass a `WaveStream` to `Init` - all that is needed is an `IWaveProvider`.

To convert yourself from `ISampleProvider` to `IWaveProvider` use `SampleToWaveProvider` or `SampleToWaveProvider16` which also converts to 16 bit and clips at the same time.

Comment: I am using the latest NAudio.I have been able to play the ISampleProvider with code similar to above, the problem was with my ISampleProvider and not with the 'IWaveProvider.Init()' method.

Comment: For all future readers: The "latest NAudio" means version 1.7, published on Oct 29, 2013.